# does SSRS have a limit on number of fields in the dataset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I have a data set:

```
select * from table1 --approximately 100 fields
join table2
on...
join table3
on...
```

The query works when I test it in SSMS.

However, when I try to run a report with this query as the dataset, I am getting:

[image]

I thought that perhaps I'm incorrectly capturing the names of the fields, so instead of doing `select *` i did `select field1, field2...field100`  but still getting the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Please note that I have indeed made sure that all the field names are unique by doing a unique filter in excel.

Comment: I would guess that there are duplicate field names in the result set.  SSMS is fine returning duplicate names at the highest level, but SSRS probably wants the names to be unique.

Comment: indeed this is definitely a good guess. yes, i did change the field names so that there were no duplicates indeed; however, still got the same result

Comment: Time for some [binary search debugging](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/50552/how-to-effectively-do-manual-debugging/181223#181223)?

Comment: You could also right-click the report in question in the Solution Explorer and click View Code. This will show you the XML behind the report template. Do a CTRL+F for 'fieldFirstName' and see if it is showing up somewhere it is not supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  This was my solution.
1)First test your Reporting boundaries, try to determine the maximum amount of fields you can display.

2)Take your main report and make it a sub report.

3)Pass the remaining values through parameters as a concatenated string

4)Use your new sub-report to parse the parameters string.

Here is some VB code to help.  Paste this in your report properties cod section.
'***************************************************************************************************************************

```
Public Function ListToString(myList As String, Delimiter As String, Optional index As Integer = 0) As String
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Purpose:
    '----This function splits a list and allows one to access the split list like a programmable array
    'Description:
    '----Input: 
    '--------myList: String containing the list created in SSRS
    '--------Delimiter: what you used to seperate/ delimit each element
    '--------index: the index you want you access
    '----Output:
    '--------ReturnString: returns Name in the format of "FirstName LastName"
    'Version Control log: (Date - Name: Description)
    '----xx/xx/xxxx     Adrian Williams     Creation of function
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Dim returnString As String = ""
    Dim myArray As String()

    myArray = myList.split(delimiter)
    returnString = trim(myArray(index))


    Return returnString
End Function
```

'***************************************************************************************************************************